# XCode project type for this application? OpenGL ES or View-Based?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, opengl-es

I was wondering what project type this application was probably developed using?

The app is called Sound Literacy.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7giaN5T7ww&feature=related

I'm new to developing, but want to create an application that uses these same features. I'm thinking either OpenGL ES Application or View-Based. What do you guys think?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "project type" really doesn't matter. All it does is give you different boilerplate code to start with. So start with whichever one seems most convenient to you.

Comment: Thanks man, I appreciate it. I thought this might be the case, I just wasn't sure.

Answer (score 0):

I would say OpenGL ES since it's a lot more customizable.